# How can I limit my concurrent calls with rest assured

Tags: multithreading, rest-assured

How can I limit/ control my concurrent request with rest assured. The REST API I'm currently testing is only limited to 3 concurrent request per account at a time which means all the other tests get a 429 response code.

An example would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As I know Rest Assured does not have such functionality. You could easily do it using test runner, e.g. TestNG, by managing parallel threads:

```
name: SingleSuite
threadCount: 3
parallel: methods

tests:
  - name: Regression
    classes:
      - test.ApiTest
```

If you want to run several accounts simultaneously you should think about making RA thread safe (or check that it has been fixed in latest versions)